# In MVC 4 How do I Add multiple Collections to a session?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, session, razor

I'm using MVC 4 with Razor Syntax to create a collection based on a class that was created using scaffolding (Database first based development) and I can add the first collection to the Session and return it to the Index view and display it on the page.

When I attempt to add a second collection to the Session Variable it gives me a error.

```
 Unable to cast object of type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EagleEye.Models.tblTask]' to type
'EagleEye.Models.tblTask'.
```

What am I doing wrong - how do I add 2 collections to the session?!

Index.cshtml (My Index view using Razor syntax)

```
@model List<myApp.Models.tblTask>
<table>
  @{

                foreach (var tblTask in Model)
                {

                        <tr>
                        <td>
                            TaskName: @tblTask.Name
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            Desc: @tblTask.Description
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            Schedule: @tblTask.Freq @tblTask.FreqUnit
                        </td>

                        <td>
                            Reocurring?: @tblTask.ReocurringTask.ToString()
                        </td>
                    </tr>       
                }      
            }
    </table>
```

Here's the "ActionResult" portion of the code from my HomeController.cs:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateTask(tblTask newTask)
    {
        var TaskCollection = new List<tblTask>();
        if (Session["TaskCollection"] != null)
        {
            TaskCollection.Add((tblTask)Session["TaskCollection"]);
        }
        TaskCollection.Add(newTask);

        Session["TaskCollection"] = TaskCollection;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var TaskCollection = new List<tblTask>();

        if (Session["TaskCollection"] != null)
        {
            TaskCollection = (List<tblTask>)Session["TaskCollection"];
        }

        return View(TaskCollection);


    }
```

When I add the first entry it works fine and shows up on my index view. When I try to add the second collection of tasks, it tells me:

```
 Unable to cast object of type
'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[EagleEye.Models.tblTask]' to type
'EagleEye.Models.tblTask'.
```

I've been fighting this for a few days now and have been developing for a while, but am just beginning to learn the power of asking questions when I'm stumped (instead of just continuing to beat my head against the wall until something caves in (often my head), so if my question is not well formed, please let me know.

Thanks!
Dan

Comment: OK... Finally I see the light! .. here's the updated code that works:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because, inside your if condition, you are casting the `Session["TaskCollection"]`(which is a collection of `tblTask` to a single instance of `tblTask`.

This should work.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateTask(tblTask newTask)
{
    var TaskCollection = new List<tblTask>();
    //Check whether the collection exist in session, If yes read it
   // & cast it to the tblTask collection & set it to the TaskCollection variable
    if (Session["TaskCollection"] != null)
    {
        TaskCollection= (List<tblTask>) Session["TaskCollection"];           
    }

    if(newTask!=null)
       TaskCollection.Add(newTask);

    //Set the updated collection back to the session
    Session["TaskCollection"] = TaskCollection;

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Seems obvious now ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I finally see the light -- Note the change in the HomeController.cs  "TaskCollection = (List)Session["TaskCollection"]; "

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult CreateTask(tblTask newTask)
    {
        var TaskCollection = new List<tblTask>();
        if (Session["TaskCollection"] != null)
        {
            //Here is the line that changed -- the following line works~
            TaskCollection = (List<tblTask>)Session["TaskCollection"];
        }
        TaskCollection.Add(newTask);

        Session["TaskCollection"] = TaskCollection;

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```